# Use AMI Image for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I would like to use `eb` to launch an elastic beanstalk instance from an AMI image. I have made an image of a previously used elastic beanstalk instance, but I have been unable to find an example of how to tell elastic beanstalk to use the AMI though a configuration file (either .config in .ebextensions or config.yml in .elasticbeanstalk). How do I add the AMI to my configuration file so it will use the AMI rather than start from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use custom AMI's with elastic beanstalk. You can configure your instances with .ebextensions files.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: Not really a helpful answer, some scenarios may call for custom ami

Comment: Incorrect answer (sometimes). Encrypted EC2 root volumes require a custom AMI.

Comment: Elasticbeanstalk now supports custom platforms. You should create custom platform instead of just changing ami.